# Issue adding child max width to parent element

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, width, each

I just ran into issue with JQuery.
I made simple drop-down navigation. It is working perfectly.

```
            <div id="navigation" class="grid-container">
                <div class="menu-wrap grid-85">
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">About</a>
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                <li><a href="">Sarsauto</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Acedelco</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">Services</a>
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                <li><a href="">Purchase</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Rental</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">MOT</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">Catalog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Contacts</a>
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                <li><a href="">Find Us</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
```

Now I am trying to make parent elements **ul.menu li** width the same as the bigest child element **ul.menu li ul.submenu**.
Here is the jquery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var maxWidth = "0px";

        $("#navigation ul.submenu").each(function(){
            var currentWidth = $(this).css("width");
            if(currentWidth > maxWidth){
                maxWidth = currentWidth;
            }
        });

        $("#navigation ul.menu li").css("width",maxWidth);
    });
```

Now, what it does is adds attribute *style* with *width=0px*, istead of **maxWidth**.
Please help me to find the issue.
Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: maxWidth nor currentWidth  shouldn't be strings... You are comparing two strings here: `if(currentWidth > maxWidth)`

Comment: thanks, that was one of main issues. still problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var maxWidth = 0;

    $("#navigation ul.submenu").each(function () {
        var currentWidth = $(this).width();
    if (currentWidth > maxWidth) {
        maxWidth = currentWidth;
    }
    });

$("#navigation ul.menu li").width(maxWidth);
});
```

Comment: This worked when I added +"px" in last row so it returns formated pixel size to element. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Precede a `+` symbol while you are retrieving the width during run time. It will convert that into an `integer` value. And you assigned `maxWidth` as a string, That will also cause problems while comparring.

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var maxWidth = 0;

        $("#navigation ul.submenu").each(function(){
            var currentWidth = +$(this).css("width");
            if(currentWidth > maxWidth){
                maxWidth = currentWidth;
            }
        });

        $("#navigation ul.menu li").css("width",maxWidth);
    });
```